# Bootstrap modal not opening on clicking image in an Angular2 app

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, twitter-bootstrap-3

I want to open a Bootstrap modal when my image or button is clicked. I have added the code but when I am clicking the image, I am getting the following error:

> ERROR ReferenceError: $ is not defined(…)

and:

> Error context

I am attaching screenshot below:

[image]

Below is my `page.html` code:

```
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Activate Modal with JavaScript</h2>
  <!-- Trigger the modal with a button -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg" id="myBtn" (click)="openmodal()">Open Modal</button>

  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

      <!-- Modal content-->
      <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
          <p>Some text in the modal.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>

</div>




<img (click)="openmodal()" src="https://img.megaobzor.com/old/hardmind/artpreview/CarZaz1.jpg" class="img-thumbnail" alt="Cinque Terre" width="304" height="236">
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

My `page.ts` code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

declare var $: any; //intentional use of jQuery

@Component({
  selector: 'app-changeimage',
  templateUrl: './changeimage.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./changeimage.component.css']
})
export class ChangeimageComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  openmodal(){
    console.log("image clicked");
 $("#myModal").modal();

$('.modal')
    .prop('class', 'modal fade') // revert to default
    .addClass( $(this).data('direction') );
$('.modal').modal('show');
  }

}
```

I am trying to follow this fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/daverogers/mu5mvba0/

Comment: have you included jquery ? Also it would be a better idea to use http://valor-software.com/ngx-bootstrap/#/modals and avoid jQuery altogether.

Comment: Do you included JQuery ? If yes, then try opening the modal without JS, but only HTML (look at bootstrap examples, you can do so just by adding specific attributes to your tags)

Comment: Yes i have added it on my html page, i have also updated in my question above, let me know where am i doing wrong

Comment: make sure that bootstrap script tag is after jquery script tag

Comment: i am using angular cli and i add css in angular-cli.json, do i need to call bootstrap js file aswell ?

Comment: I have added but still getting the same error

Comment: also installed jquery `npm install jquery --save` and added in angular-cli.json ,  nothing seems to work